# Tidyversing working R code with a for loop

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a dataset of pairs of cities V1 and V2. Each cities has a population v1_pop2015 and v2_pop2015.

I would like to create a new dataset with only the cityCode of the biggest city and its populated added of the population of the smallest.

I was able to create the output I want with a for loop. For educationnal purpose, I tried to do it using tidyverse tools without success.

This is a working sample

```
library(tidyverse)

## Sample dataset
pairs_pop <- structure(list(cityCodeV1 = c(20073, 20888, 20222, 22974, 23792, 
20779), cityCodeV2 = c(20063, 204024, 20183, 20406, 23586, 23595
), v1_pop2015 = c(414, 682, 497, 3639, 384, 596), v2_pop2015 = c(384, 
757, 5716, 315, 367, 1303)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

pairs_pop
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   cityCodeV1 cityCodeV2 v1_pop2015 v2_pop2015
#> *      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1      20073      20063        414        384
#> 2      20888     204024        682        757
#> 3      20222      20183        497       5716
#> 4      22974      20406       3639        315
#> 5      23792      23586        384        367
#> 6      20779      23595        596       1303


#### This is working !!!
clean_df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = 2, nrow = dim(pairs_pop)[1])),c("to_keep", "to_keep_pop"))
# For each row, determine which city is the biggest and adds the two cities population
for (i  in 1:dim(pairs_pop)[1]) {


  if(pairs_pop$v1_pop2015[i] > pairs_pop$v2_pop2015[i])
    {
      clean_df$to_keep[i] = pairs_pop$cityCodeV1[i]
      clean_df$to_keep_pop[i] = pairs_pop$v1_pop2015[i] + pairs_pop$v2_pop2015[i]
    } 
  else 
    {
      clean_df$to_keep[i] = pairs_pop$cityCodeV2[i]
      clean_df$to_keep_pop[i] = pairs_pop$v1_pop2015[i] + pairs_pop$v2_pop2015[i]
    }

}
clean_df 
#>   to_keep to_keep_pop
#> 1   20073         798
#> 2  204024        1439
#> 3   20183        6213
#> 4   22974        3954
#> 5   23792         751
#> 6   23595        1899
```

This is where I'm stucked

```
### trying to tidy it  with rowwise, mutate and a function

v1_sup_tov2 <- function(x){
  print(x)
  if(x$v1_pop2015 > x$v2_pop2015){

    return (TRUE)
  }
  return(FALSE)
}

to_clean_df2 <- pairs_pop %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate_if(v1_sup_tov2,
            to_keep = cityCodeV1,
            to_delete= cityCodeV2,
            to_keep_pop = v1_pop2015 + v2_pop2015)
```

The expected output is a dataframe with 2 colums like this:
to_keep: cityCode of the city I want to keep
to_keep_pop: population of that city

```
clean_df 
#>   to_keep to_keep_pop
#> 1   20073         798
#> 2  204024        1439
#> 3   20183        6213
#> 4   22974        3954
#> 5   23792         751
#> 6   23595        1899
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this?

```
library(dplyr)

## Sample dataset
pairs_pop <- structure(
  list(cityCodeV1 = c(20073, 20888, 20222, 22974, 23792, 20779),
       cityCodeV2 = c(20063, 204024, 20183, 20406, 23586, 23595),
       v1_pop2015 = c(414, 682, 497, 3639, 384, 596),
       v2_pop2015 = c(384, 757, 5716, 315, 367, 1303)),
  row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

clean_df <- transmute(pairs_pop,
              to_keep = if_else(v1_pop2015 > v2_pop2015, cityCodeV1, cityCodeV2),
              to_keep_pop = v1_pop2015 + v2_pop2015)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just in case one day you get multiple cities with v1, v2, v3, ...
Do not forget to keep all information in your dataframe so that you know what value is related to what. A tidy dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)

## Sample dataset
pairs_pop <- structure(
  list(cityCodeV1 = c(20073, 20888, 20222, 22974, 23792, 20779),
       cityCodeV2 = c(20063, 204024, 20183, 20406, 23586, 23595),
       v1_pop2015 = c(414, 682, 497, 3639, 384, 596),
       v2_pop2015 = c(384, 757, 5716, 315, 367, 1303)),
  row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# Tidy dataset with all information that was in columns

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

tidy_pairs <- pairs_pop %>% 
  mutate(city = 1:n()) %>% 
  gather("key", "value", -city) %>% 
  mutate(ville = str_extract(key, "([[:digit:]])"),
         key = case_when(
           grepl("cityCode", key) ~ "cityCode",
           grepl("pop", key) ~ "pop",
           TRUE ~ "other"
         )) %>% 
  spread(key, value)
```

[image: tidy_pairs]

And then you can apply the test you want

```
tidy_pairs %>% 
  group_by(city) %>% 
  summarise(to_keep = cityCode[pop == max(pop)],
            to_keep_pop = sum(pop))
```

[image: summarise]